# A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to use `create-react-app` to generate a new React app.

I run

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

But I am getting this error:

> A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an
> outdated version of create-react-app. Please note that global installs
> of create-react-app are no longer supported. You can fix this by
> running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove
> create-react-app before using create-react-app again.

I tried running

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

and I verified that it does not exist globally, but still getting this error.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found a real simple fix for this.

```
which create-react-app | xargs rm
```

I guess there is some artifact from an old install that doesn't show in the npm global list that is causing the problem.

Once it is removed there is no need to install anything. Just run:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

And it will work now.